# Install IIS 6 scripting tools on windows 2003

Tags: scripting, iis-6, installation, windows-server-2003

I want to log worker process recycling, By default, IIS does not log worker process recycling events:
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/87892589-4eda-4003-b4ac-3879eac4bf48.mspx?mfr=true

For this, I need the folder   %systemroot%\inetpub\adminscripts
This folder contains AdsUtil.vbs administration Script
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d3df4bc9-0954-459a-b5e6-7a8bc462960c.mspx?mfr=true

The problem is that my server does not have this folder - i.e.  Adsutil.vbs Administration Script  is not installed.

Now there are many ways to install IIS 6 scripting tools on IIS 7 -
http://myhosting.com/wiki/IIS_6_Scripting_Tools

But nowhere can I find how to install it on Windows 2003 if it does not exist.
The server is set up as an application server and IIS 6 has been running perfectly on it without any problems so it is not that IIS 6 is not installed

I have tried doing what technet says
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb808814.aspx
but when I get to   part 2:
To install required Windows Server 2003 components

1.In Control Panel, select Add or Remove Programs.
2.In the Add or Remove Programs dialog box, click Add/Remove Windows Components.
3.In the Windows Components Wizard, select Application Server, and then click Details.
4.In the Application Server dialog box, select ASP.NET, select Internet Information Services (IIS), and then click OK.

Now I am lost and dont know where to go. I dont even think this is the correct tab.

So I tried server roles
Manage your server - Manage this application server - and now I am lost here - it shows
Application server
-.net configuration 1.1
-IIS Manager
-Component services

But nowhere can I see how to install the required scripts. The server is already set up as a "Application Server (IIS, ASP.net)

Please help

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, AdsUtil.vbs should be in the %systemroot%\Inetpub\AdminScripts folder on Windows Server 2003 (I.e. c:\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs).  I believe it is normally installed with IIS but if you moved your IIS root elsewhere at some point it may have gotten lost in the shuffle.

To get it back you can:

1. Grab it from another machine that DOES have it.  adsutil.vbs does not have any baggage/dependencies other than cscript that I am aware of so you can just copy it off another server.
2. Extract it from the Windows Server 2003 install disk using 7Zip or some other extraction/explorer utility.
3. Check to see if you already have a copy in your Service Pack install files (I.e. C:\Windows\ServicePackFiles\i386\adsutil.vbs